# How to make a function that remove duplicates from an passed array

Tags: c++

It's my first year learning the C++ language. I want to make a function that removes duplicates from a passed array. I tried to doing it with many different kinds of logic, but sadly I have failed on all of them. I hope someone can help me.

Here is my code:

```cpp
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void RemoveDuplicates(int * array,int n,int *&arrayb)
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        y++;
        if (array[x]!=array[y])
        {
            arrayb[x]=array[x];
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        else 
        {
            arrayb[x]=array[x];
            x++;
            y++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int * array = new int [n];
    int * arrayb = new int [n];
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    RemoveDuplicates(array,n,arrayb);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << arrayb[i] <<"  ";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting errors. You should be able to paste your code as text, and use back-ticks for formatting. In fact, you *must* paste the code here, along with a clear explanation of how the code fails.

Comment: Thank you for editing my code, When "paste your code here" poped up for me I pasted it but only the first line which is using name space std; appeared on the window of code.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: Ignore the order of content, and prefer to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Vectors are easier to pass, expand dynamically as necessary and have a `size()` method.  You could pass the vector *by reference* so it can be modified.  No need for a second array.

Comment: FYI, for every `new []` there needs to be a matching `delete[]`.  Search the internet for "c++ memory leak".

Comment: I don't know how to do this really, I am not sure it's even allowed because it's the first year for me to learn this language so I don't really know.

Comment: it's not allowed to use vectors.

Comment: even if I used delete the logic is wrong so I don't get the right output, some cases work such as [10 20 10 20] but some indices of the new array takes garbage values and some cases just goes into a huge logical error

Comment: @MohamedMohsen You are allowed to use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)?

Comment: @Zoso Nope it's not

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this, I had this piece of code in my repo

```cpp
void remove_duplicates(int arr[], int &a_size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a_size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a_size;j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                for (int k = j; k < a_size; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                }
                a_size--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like number is undefined, and why did you use it?

Comment: You are correct, I edited the code, the initialization should be number in stead of "item"

Comment: @enriqueojedalara `i > a_size` should be `i < a_size`. Also, at no point is `a_size` being modified, so there is no need to pass it by reference.  Since this code is modifying the input array inline, it would make sense to modify `a_size` to reflect the new array size when the function is done. `a_size` could be decremented after the inner-most `for` loop is done. Which BTW, that loop should be `for (k = j + 1; k < a_size; k++) { arr[k-1] = arr[k]; }` instead. And the middle `for` loop should increment `j` only on iterations that do not encounter a duplicate `number`, otherwise you will skip e

Comment: I tested your function on my code after some edits it worked, but shouldn't the array be sent as Aliace from the original array like this int *&Array? I tried it but it just print the same array entered.

Comment: @enriqueojedalara Given the number of bugs in this code originally, I'm worried for what you had in your repo. I hope you didn't use that code often, otherwise you should have tested it better.

Comment: @MohamedMohsen There is no need to pass the array by reference, since the function is not modifying where the `int*` pointer is pointing at, it is only rearranging the contents of the array.

Comment: Aha okay I now understand the passing of array, because basically the pointer only points to the first element, but I can't understand what do you mean by "Given the number of bugs in this code originally, I'm worried for what you had in your repo. I hope you didn't use that code often, otherwise you should have tested it better"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Very very very old repo, it was writen in 2006, I did not noticed and I will test next time before paste a code, anyway I hope the main idea would be helpful for Mohamed and thank you so much for your help

Comment: @MohamedMohsen "*I can't understand what do you mean by ...*" - that comment was directed to enriqueojedalara, not to you. Notice all the bugs I was pointing out, that he had to correct in edits? He said the code came from his personal repo(sitory), so I was commenting how worried I was that his repo had such a buggy function in it that needed fixing, that he chose to use for his answer to you.

Comment: @MohamedMohsen For the records and fot the archive I just edited the code and fix the issues, I also tested it (I should did it since the begining)

Comment: @enriqueojedalara Yea now it works fine, but can you explain to me the logic of this please? I am still learning and I want to understand the Algorithm of this function, thanks in advance..

Comment: @MohamedMohsen I will try to explain this briefly, we use the first two iterations to compare one element against the next one and see if are the same value (duplicated), if it is duplicated then we use the third iteration to move the rest of the elements one position replacing the duplicated element, because the code remove one element the original size should be reduced by one (a_size--)  and to avoid skip the element removed we must move back one position in the second iteration (j--) so we are not skip any element in the iteration, Hope this make sense to you!